# copy array of char to another without strcpy in c

Tags: c++

> copy x to y without header files string.h

> copy array of char to another without strcpy in c++

> input : **car a car**

> i want output without space or garbage : **caracar**

but ouput contain garbage or
if i put : y[50]={0}
ouput is one ward just
output is**car** just

i want output without garbage and "caracar"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int i;
   char x[50], y[50] ;
   cout << "Enter : ";
   scanf_s("%[^\n]", x, sizeof(x));
   for (i = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++)
       if ((x[i] >= 'a' && x[i] <= 'z') || (x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] <= 'Z'))
           y[i] = x[i];
   y[i] = '\0';

   cout << y;
}
```

output: caracar without space or grabage

Comment: What about using the Standard Library and not C headers?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger and watch how the array elements are changed? Think about what happens when the condition is false.

Comment: Have a second iterator `int j=0`. Then use it to track write position. `y[j++] = x[i];`

Comment: C or C++, pick one.

Comment: @Holy Using `cout <<` ... so it's C++.

Comment: @AdrianMole I can manually fix the question, but it's also important to teach the OP so they can do it themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using only a *single* 'index' variable (`i`) for both source and destination strings. However, you should only increment the *destination* index if you actually copy a character. As it stands, when the source character is not copied, you are still incrementing the destination index, so you are skipping characters in that buffer, which are left in their original (i.e. uninitialized/garbage) states.

You need a separate index (let's call it `j`) for your destination buffer; initialize that to zero (as with `i`) at the start of the `for` loop but only increment it if we actually copy something (this can be done best using the post-increment operator inside the `[...]` for the destination:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j; // Need 2 index vars: one for source, one for destination
    char x[50], y[50];
    cout << "Enter : ";
    scanf_s("%[^\n]", x, static_cast<int>(sizeof(x))); // Note last argument is "int"
    for (i = j = 0; x[i] != '\0'; i++) // Set "j" to zero at loop start ...
        if ((x[i] >= 'a' && x[i] <= 'z') || (x[i] >= 'A' && x[i] <= 'Z')) {
            y[j++] = x[i]; // ...but only increment it on copy!
        }
    y[j] = '\0'; // Use Last "j" for position of nul terminator
    cout << y;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. More C++-ish than working with raw arrays and indices, while being not as high level as using `std::ranges::remove_copy_if`:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter : ";
    std::string x;
    std::getline(std::cin, x);

    std::string y;
    for ((unsigned char const e : x)
        if (std::isalpha(e))
            y.push_back(e);

    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

*Additional credits: HolyBlackCat and Adrian Mole.*

Comment: `std::isalpha(e)` is UB for negative character codes. Use `std::isalpha((unsigned char)e)`, OR just change the type of `e` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: On the one hand you say *while not relying on library functions* but then use `std::isalpha()` in your code. If that ain't a "library function," then what is it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks, will look into it and update the answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole Well okay, it is... I considered the core of the question to be "How to fill `y` given some condition?" I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> copy array of char to another without strcpy in c++

You can for example use `std::ranges::copy`.

> without space

You can use `std::ranges::remove_copy_if`. Example:

```
auto is_space = [](char c) {
    return c == ' ';
};
std::ranges::remove_copy_if(x, y, is_space);
```

Comment: True, but manually writing a loop is a great learning exercise.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure. It's just not necessary within the parameters of the given exercise. Learning to use the standard algorithms is also a great learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your excercise is more 'C' but the solution would look something like this since you require not to use  (which is not recommended for production code)
:

```
int main()
{
    const size_t buf_size = 64;
    const char* input = "car a car";
    char output[buf_size];

    const char* input_ptr = &input[0];
    const char* output_ptr_end = &output[buf_size - 2]; // leave room for one extra trailing 0
    char* output_ptr = &output[0];

    while ((*input_ptr != 0) && (output_ptr < output_ptr_end))
    {
        if (*input_ptr == ' ') input_ptr++; // skip space
        *output_ptr++ = *input_ptr++;
    }
    *output_ptr = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char input[32];  // obtained text
char output[32];

char*in_pos     =   input;
char*out_pos    =   output;

for(char cur_char; (cur_char=*in_pos++); ) // while NULL not encountered
{
    if(
        (cur_char>='A'&&cur_char<='Z')|| // uppercase
        (cur_char>='a'&&cur_char<='z')|| // lowercase
        (cur_char>='0'&&cur_char<='9')   // digits
    )
        *out_pos++  =   cur_char; // output cur_char
}

*out_pos = 0; // NULL termination
```